# Rótulo de dados sobrepondo

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Desejo manter os rótulos de dados organizados de forma que não se sobreponham entre si.

A ideia é mantê-los acima do `geom_point` ou abaixo.. dependendo da posição da linha.

Como posso proceder ?

Segue o comando simplificado e uma figura como exemplo do problema.

```
dt <- data.frame(periodo = c("JUN", "JUL","AGO","SET","OUT","NOV","DEZ"), 
                 diam = c(2.76,2.75,2.55,2.81,2.1,2.2,2.34,2.89,2.96,2.77,2.88,2.99,2.10,2.11))
dt$Variedade <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = nrow(dt)/2)
dt$periodo <- factor(dt$periodo, levels = c("JUN", "JUL","AGO","SET","OUT","NOV","DEZ"))

ggplot(dt, aes(x = periodo, y = diam, group = Variedade)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_label(aes(label = diam)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(2,4), limits = c(1,5))
```

[image: exemplo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar a opção `nudge_*` para deslocar os rótulos. Para um maior controle, como as linhas se cruzam, pode fazer o deslocamento dependendo da posição de uma Variedade em relação a outra:

```
adj <- with(dt, diam[Variedade == "A"] - diam[Variedade == "B"])
adj <- ifelse(adj < 0, -.2, .2)

ggplot(dt, aes(x = periodo, y = diam, group = Variedade, color = Variedade)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_label(aes(label = diam), nudge_y = c(adj, -adj)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1,4))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Use o pacote `ggrepel` e a função `geom_text_repel`

```
library(ggrepel)
dt <- data.frame(periodo = c("JUN", "JUL","AGO","SET","OUT","NOV","DEZ"), 
             diam = c(2.76,2.75,2.55,2.81,2.1,2.2,2.34,2.89,2.96,2.77,2.88,2.99,2.10,2.11))
dt$Variedade <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = nrow(dt)/2)
dt$periodo <- factor(dt$periodo, levels = c("JUN", "JUL","AGO","SET","OUT","NOV","DEZ"))
ggplot(dt, aes(x = periodo, y = diam, group = Variedade, label = diam)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()+
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(fill = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(2,4), limits = c(1,5))
```

Comment: Ao rodar o comando acima com o argumento `ggrepel::geom_label_repel(fill = "white")` está me retornando ao seguinte erro:  `Error in repel_boxes2(data_points = as.matrix(x$data[, c("x", "y")]),  : pacote 'Rcpp_precious_remove' não oferece a função 'Rcpp'.`